# How to restrict HTTP call until previous one is finished

Tags: angular, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I have a very tricky situation in my `Angular 2` app. In my auth service, I have a function `loggedIn` which reads jwt access token from local storage and checks if it is expired or not and is used to gate the routes. It is called in `canActivate` implementations:

```
canActivate(....):Observable<boolean>{
    return this.checkLogin();
}

checkLogin():Observable<boolean>{
    return this._authSvc.isLoggedIn();
}

///AUTHSERVICE

isLoggedIn():Observable<boolean> {
    let ex = tokenNotExpired('access_token');
    if (ex) {
      let jwt = new JwtHelper();

      let t = jwt.decodeToken(localStorage['access_token']);
      if (t.Id) {
        this.Id = t.Id;
      }
    }
    return Observable.of(new Boolean()).map(x => ex);
}
```

Recently, I implemented the capability to refresh the token on the backend (`ASP.Net Web API 2`). Now, the idea is to refresh the access token if it is expired using the refresh token. I tried to plumb it from `isLoggedIn` method. If the access token is expired, I will return `Observable<boolean>` as:

```
if(ex){
}else{
    return this.refreshToken();//<---NEW OBSERVABLE
}
```

from below function:

```
/*method to refresh the access token*/
refreshToken():Observable<boolean>{
    //setup stuff
    var res= this.http.post(url,data,opts).map(r=> data=r.json());

    res.subscribe(data=>{
        localStorage['access_token'] = data.access_token;
        localStorage['refresh_token'] = data.refresh_token;
        let jwt = new JwtHelper();
        let t = jwt.decodeToken(localStorage['access_token']);
        if (t.Id) {
          this.Id = t.Id;
        }
    }, error=>{console.log(error);
    });

    return res;
}
```

But this is causing all the hell to break loose. There are endless requests which all fail (as the first one resets the `refresh token`).

What I want to do is make only one request even if the function is triggered multiple times from `canActivate`. Is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind storing the state of the current request in your class this might be a viable option.

```
isPendingSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
isPending$: Obserrvable<boolean> = this.isPendingSubject.asObservable();

/*method to refresh the access token*/
refreshToken():Obserrvable<boolean> {
    //setup stuff
    const refreshIsPending = this.isPendingSubject.value();
    if (this.refreshIsPending) return this.isPending$;
    this.isPendingSubject.next(true);
    this.refreshIsPending = true;
    var res = this.http.post(url,data,opts).map(r=> data=r.json());

    res.subscribe(data=>{
        localStorage['access_token'] = data.access_token;
        localStorage['refresh_token'] = data.refresh_token;
        let jwt = new JwtHelper();
        let t = jwt.decodeToken(localStorage['access_token']);
        if (t.Id) {
          this.Id = t.Id;
        }
        this.isPendingSubject.next(false);
    }, error=>{console.log(error);
  });
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had mulled on this and even tried it, but as I needed to return `Observable<boolean>` to be consumed up the chain, it changes the things simple `return` will not work.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Are you doing something with the returned subscription?

Comment: Yes, it is used in `CanActivate` ultimately.

Comment: Ok I have made a few changes to ensure that a Observable is being returned. Is that useful, or have I gone down the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is basically sharing a single subscription among multiple subscribers you can keep the Observable in a property and just use the `share()` operator to avoid making multiple `this.http.post()` calls.

```
private refresh$: Observable;

refreshToken(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (!this.refresh$) {
        this.refresh$ = this.http.post(url,data,opts)
            .map(r=> data=r.json())
            .share();

        this.refresh$.subscribe(...);
    }

    return this.refresh$;
}
```

I obviously didn't test it but I hope you get the point. When you call the method multiple times you always receive the same Observable and the `share()` operator makes sure there's always only one active HTTP reqeust at the time.

Comment: Well, no... I had `share` there but still got endless requests! let me try again with `refresh$`

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Then you're doing something wrong :)

Comment: well maybe. but `Observable` is not being allowed without `type argument`. If it is put as `Observable<boolean>` subscribe gets a `boolean` instead of `data` from `map` function :(

Comment: In RxJS you can always set types when calling operators eg.: `.map<number, string>(val => 'a');`. This takes a number as an input and sends strings as output.